# CoreBluetooth - The request is not supported. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

Problem : 
I get a "Request is not supported" error. This happens when I write a characteristic.

Scenario : 
The peripheral is also an iPhone.

Basically, I can communicate to the peripheral with ease except for a certain scenario.

The error happens...

1. Say during a connection, I turn off the bluetooth or go to another screen (TabBar selecting another bar, not going back in navigation) which cancels the connection.
2. The central receives the error and resets the data back to scanning.
3. I then turn on or go back to the connection screen by pressing the tab bar.
4. The peripheral starts to advertise again.
5. The central detects again the peripheral and does a connection. Until I write and send a request to the peripheral to connect. Then the error happens.

Whats weird is that the peripheral receives the write request. But during that time, the central is disconnected already.

Has anyone have the same experience? Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to detect the problem.

What I only did was to **unsubscribe the central** the peripheral was connecting to. It was missing in the clean up.